# Codeigniter Call to undefined method CI_DB_mysqli_result::num_row()

Tags: php, codeigniter

I use this code for login_model:

class Login_model extends  CI_Model{

```
function __construct(){
    parent:: __construct();
}

function check(){
    $username = $this->input->post('username',true);
    $password = $this->input->post('password',true);
    $remember = $this->input->post('remember',true);


    /*
    $this->db->select('username','username');
    $this->db->select('password','password');
    $this->db->where('username',"$username");
    $this->db->where('password',md5($password));
    $this->db->from('user');
    $this->db->limit(1);
    $is = $this->db->count_all_results();
    */
    $user = $this->db->get_where ('user',array('username'=>$username,'password'=>md5($password)));
    $is = $user->num_row();

    if($is>0){

        $id = $user->row(0)->id;
        $data_session=array(
            'username'=>'$username',
            'login'=> true,
            'id'=>$id
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($data_session);

        if($remember == 1){
           $login_text= $username.'_isLogin_'. $id;
            $this->load->library('encrypt');
            $cookie_value = $this->encrypt->encode($login_text,ENCRYPT_KEY);

           $data_cookie=array(
               'name'=>'Ahmadreza',
               'value'=>$cookie_value,
               'expire'=>time()+60*60*24*365
           );
            $this->input->set_cookie($data_cookie);
        }
        redirect('post/index');
    }else{
        redirect('login/index');
    }


}
```

}

but show this  !
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPQLX.png)
now how can I solve this problem.

Thank you.

Error  Image :  https://i.stack.imgur.com/MPQLX.png

Comment: SOLVE just a litter problem from my code :
i use 
$is = $user->num_row();
but i should used :
$is = $user->num_rows();
i didnt use "s" after row 
just this

Comment: Assuming that code will just work is the main cause for errors. You need to always check for errors, where they can occur, even if you think nothing bad will happen.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is `num_rows()` and not `num_row()`

Replace,

```
$is = $user->num_row();
```

with

```
$is = $user->num_rows();
```

Answer (score 1):

there is no any function call `num_row();` in Codeigniter.

So correct way is `num_rows();` [`num_rows() Function in Codeigniter`](http://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html#result-helper-methods)

So Final Well-form code is

```
$is = $user->num_rows();
```

> **Note :**
>   Not all database drivers have a native way of getting the total number of rows for a result set. When this is the case, all of the data is prefetched and `count()` is manually called on the resulting array in order to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

Check Codeginiter [documentaion](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/database/results.html)

Its $user->num_rows();